# Sessions in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

If ActiveRecord::Store is being deprecated, what is the suggested method for maintaining session? Is encrypted cookie store the new standard? What if you want to maintain >4kb in state?

Answer (score 6):

In Rails 4, include`gem 'activerecord-session_store'` in your Gemfile and run bundle install. Complete the migration and configuration as per https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store notes.

The other alternative is using the 'dalli' gem for session management.

Answer (score 0):

Look out for the file named `session_store.rb` inside your `config/initializers` folder. There you should setup which kind of session you would like to use. A standard, cookie based one, should be like:

```
ProjectName::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_project_name_session'
```

After that all you need to do is call the hash `session` from within your controllers. You can set any value there and it will persist in between requests.

As in [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration):

> config.session_store is usually set up in config/initializers/session_store.rb and specifies what class to use to store the session. Possible values are :cookie_store which is the default, :mem_cache_store, and :disabled. The last one tells Rails not to deal with sessions. Custom session stores can also be specified (...)

Comment: I'm curious why :active_record_store is being deprecated and what is the best alternative if I want to maintain the state on the server rather than the client.

Comment: I think active_record store is not deprecated, it is just 'gemified' to increase rails' modularity.